# @IdClass Does Not Generate Foreign Key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entities:

```java
public class UserGroupId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Integer group;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String productId) {
        this.userId = productId;
    }

    public Integer getGroupId() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(Integer group) {
        this.group = group;
    }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_interest")
@IdClass(UserGroupId.class)
public class UserInterest extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    public String getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void setGroup(Group product) {
        this.group = product;
    }
}
```

Hibernate does not generate a foreign key association between UserInterest and Group. How can I solve this ?

BONUS: I want to rename `group` to `groupId` in UserGroupId. How can I map the association while keeping the naming `group` in UserInterest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `@Column` annotations from the `UserGroupId` and it will work. Take a look [here](https://github.com/bdshadow/stackoverflow/tree/master/hibernate/question69627280/src/main/java/io/bdshadow/question69627280) at a working example. Also, look at [the example 134 in the hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated).

Unfortunately, you can't rename the `group` variable to `groupId` in `UserGroupId`. In this case, you will have an exception:

```java
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property of @IdClass not found in entity io.bdshadow.UserInterest: groupId
```

A good alternative where you can do this is `@EmbeddedId` in combination with `@MapsId`.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_interest")
public class UserInterest {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupId userGroupId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("groupId")
    private Group group;
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class UserGroupId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    private Integer groupId;
```

You can find full working example [here](https://github.com/bdshadow/stackoverflow/tree/master/hibernate/question69627280embedable/src/main/java/io/bdshadow/question69627280)